# Spring Boot - JSP Form Submit Issue in War

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created an application in Spring Boot having /newJobPost GET mapping serving a form, in action attribute for JSP form I used action="/addJobPost".

Running the application:

Case 1: Running this as Java application from eclipse it serves localhost:8080/newEmployee. On submit, the form gets submitted.

Case 2: I now deploy this as a war file (employee.war). localhost:8080/employee/newJobPost, it gives me the add employee form. On submit I am redirected to localhost:8080/addJobPost as in Case 1.

As the war file name is not present an error is thrown.

To deploy this as war I updated the action in form as /employee/addJobPost, it works in war but now breaks in Case 1.

Is there any configuration that can handle this issue.

Application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

jobpost.jsp

```
 <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="jobPost" action="/addJobPost">
     <form:label path="technology">Technology</form:label>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </form:form>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newJobPost")
    public ModelAndView newJobPost(Model model){

        return new ModelAndView("jobpost", "jobPost", new JobPost());       
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addJobPost", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveJobPost(@ModelAttribute("jobPost") JobPost jobPost,
                                    BindingResult result,  ModelMap model) {        

        ModelAndView modelAndView =  new ModelAndView("redirect:/allJobPost");

        jobPostService.addJobPost(jobPost);

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Comment: if you can use separate application yml for eclipse and deploying then for your eclipse deployment you can use this property server.servlet.context-path=/employee

Comment: Let me know if my understanding is correct, create 2 property file, all the redirects in eclipse will work on default localhost:8080/xxx while in case of war deployment server.servlet.context-path will be appended @GrinishNepal

Comment: Nothing to do on the war prop since it already has the context but for eclipse u will need to add that atleast from consistency prespective. The idea is to have context path in both.